# Abstraer value de un select y estoyb trabajando con beatifulsoup en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

tengo la siguiente estructura html y quiero extraer el value del tercer option del select con beatiful soup

```html
<div class="box">
  <form id="busquedaFiltros" style="margin: 0;" class="form-horizontal" action="busquedaform.html" method="post">
    <div id="divCombos">
      <div id="djT">
        <label for="aparta">caserio<span class="msjError"> (*)</span></label>
      </div>
      <div id="djV">
        <select id="casas" name="casas" class="cuerpo6 form-control" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'">
          <option onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'" value="">--Seleccionar</option>
          <option value="24454">casa1</option>
          <option value="43053">casa2</option>
          <option value="61095">casa3</option>
          <option value="83194">casa4</option>
        </select>

      </div>
      <div id="popup02f" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <span id="span01" onclick="popup02f()" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'"></span>
      </div>
```

y tengo esto en python pero no me devuelve el valor esperado

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r1.text, "html.parser") # Convertir de string a html
distrijudi = soup.find("select",id='casas').find("option",text='casa1')

print(distrijudi)
```

Comment: ¿De casualidad es esto lo que buscas `distrijudi['value']`?

Comment: No funciono este metodo

Comment: ¿Lo que buscas es obtener el valor `24454`?

Comment: si tiene toda la razon

Comment: Al menos aquí: https://repl.it/@pmoracho/Bs4Test pareciera que estuviera haciéndolo bien